# VBA Multiple Selection Drop List for Entire Row

Tags: excel, vba, multipleselection

I have been trying to have multiple selections from a drop-down list. I was able to make it work for specific cells, but I can't figure out a way to make the formula work for the entire row.

Here is my code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Address = "$D$2" Or Target.Address = "$D$3" Or Target.Address = "$D$4" Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I tried using Target.Address = Range"$D$2:$D$13" with varying () and "" and it didn't work.
I want to be able to apply the multiple selections to the entire row in my table in one formula.

Comment: `IF Not Intersect(Target, Range("D2:D13") is nothing then`

Comment: ...and add a check to make sure `Target.Cells.Count` is 1

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you for the advice I plugged in this, and it is still not working, any other suggestions would be appreciated.                       
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D2:D13")) Is Nothing Then
  If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Column = 4 Then

Answer (score 0):

This might work, by checking column number instead of A1 address of the target.

```
'
'If target.Address = "$D$2" Or target.Address = "$D$3" Or target.Address = "$D$4" Then
'
If target.Cells.Count = 1 And target.Column = 4 Then
```